# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module - when using ESM package with Axios 1.2.1

Tags: node.js, axios, es6-modules

Steps to reproduce:

- Run:

  ```bash
  npm i axios@1.2.1
  npm i esm@3.2.25
  ```
- Create `index.js` file and enter the following:

  ```javascript
  import axios from 'axios';
  console.log(axios);
  ```
- Run:

  ```bash
  node -r esm index.js
  ```

You should see the following error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module .../node_modules/axios/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

If you follow the same steps but install version `0.21.1` of Axios instead, it works as expected.

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: Node version 16.18.1

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using the esm package though; with your version of Node native esm modules have long since been supported. Instead of using esm just put `"type": "module"` in your package.json and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I have narrowed down the problem as much as I could to provide a simple example. In fact, my project relies on Vue 2 at the moment. In order to use `"type": "module"` I would need to upgrade to a newer version of Vue and Vue CLI. Which is something I have to do anyway, but I was curious to know if there was another way around it. It seems the esm package is not very actively maintained anymore as it was last published 4 years ago. I think for now I will need to stick to the older version of axios. Thank you for your engagement anyway 

Comment: Sure. That package is probably deprecated given that Node has had native esm support for several large releases already. My guess is that esm only supports import statements and not require, which leads to the error?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. I installed a different axios version. It worked

```
npm install axios@0.21.1
```